# Align baseline with bottom of inline-block

Tags: html, css

The texts baseline of inline-block is not aligning at the bottom.

How do you align the radical at the bottom of inline-block instead of text bottom (baseline)?

[Currently i have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wnnc.png)

[The goal is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHh6o.png)

Current Code

https://jsfiddle.net/x9ugahdb/1/

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
}

.radical {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.radicalData {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="radical">√</span>
  <span class="radical">hello</span>
  <span class="radicalData"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use `✓`(check mark) instead of `√`(square root mark)

Comment: I'll be scaling the container. It'll look dissimilar to a square root when it's twice the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could treat the square root mark `√` as content via an `::after` selector. From there use `position: absolute` along with `top: 6px` to layer it over the bordered span.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="radical2"></span>
    <span class="radical">hello</span>
    <span class="radicalData"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 body {
     font-size:28.8px;
     font-family:"Symbola";
     vertical-align:bottom;
}

 .parent{
     height:200px;
}

 .radical {
     border:1px solid #000;
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-align:bottom;
}

 .radical2 {
     border:1px solid #000;
     display:inline-block;
     height: 33px;
     position: relative;
     vertical-align:bottom;
     width: 20px;
}

 .radical2::after {
     content: "√";
     height: 33px;
     position: absolute;
     margin-bottom: -10px;
     top: 7px;
     z-index: 1;
}

 .radicalData {
     height:200px;
}
```

Working Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x9ugahdb/19/).

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the second inline-block to move its baseline to the bottom then keep the default alignment:

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
}

.radical {
  display: inline-block;
}

.radicalData {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="radical">√</span>
  <span class="radical" style="overflow:hidden;">hello</span>
  <span class="radicalData"></span>
</div>
```

You can also adjust the `line-height` like this:

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
}

.radical {
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
  vertical-align:bottom
}

.radicalData {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="radical" style="line-height:12px;">√</span>
  <span class="radical">hello</span>
  <span class="radicalData"></span>
</div>
```